# Paper Indexed by SCI

Tags: ieee, indexing, bioinformatics, web-of-science

One of my papers is online published with volume, issue, and page number. The journal is published by IEEE and SCI-indexed with high impact factor. I need a report from Web-of-Science to obtain the results that indicates that my paper is SCI indexed. But, unfortunately, Web-of-Science does not able to search the paper. The paper is online on October. It is non-trivial to estimate the time.

Possible duplicate: [Here](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/63599/is-there-documentation-on-how-long-it-takes-before-publications-are-indexed-by-s)

- Is there any other way to say that my paper is SCI-indexed?
- Any expected time?
- Any help from IEEE or Web-of-Science?

Comment: if it's online, why you need to prove that it is indexed? Just write it yourself and let them find it (whoever might need the information)

Comment: I did the same. They ask for the report from web of science.

Comment: In my experience Web of Science can be terribly slow with updating such things.

Answer (score 2):

Web of Science has a lag of potentially several months before a given paper from an indexed journal is uploaded. There is (I believe) nothing at all you can do about this - it's simply a matter of their workflow taking time due to the level of manual involvement needed. I would normally say that you could reasonably expect it to be up after about three months - but I wouldn't in the least be surprised if it takes longer, especially if it was up as some kind of "advance publication" and its official publication date is later than October.

Howver, I've never heard of anyone asking for proof a specific *paper* is indexed - the decision to index covers the journal, not individual papers, so it's normal to talk about "a paper published in an ISI-indexed journal" in this context. I would point them to the entry for this title in *Journal Citation Reports* or similar, to confirm that it is included, which implicitly states your paper will be indexed as part of it.

Comment: This is simply ridiculous. I also knew that if the journal is SCI-indexed (2nd ranking in Telecommunications by Impact Factor), then obviously the paper published in that journal would be included in web of science. I really don't know why they are asking for that report.

Comment: Anyway, do you have any source that indicates the above statement?

Comment: I believe you could get a screenshot about the journal being indexed.

Comment: @mithun I'm sure if you dug through the WoS or JCR helppages you could find something stating explicitly that indexing is on a journal level, but I don't have one to hand.