# Scopus: Inclusion of papers

Tags: publications, scopus

I have some papers published in journals that are approved by Scopus. But these papers are not included in Scopus. How can I get get them included?

Answer (score 1):

Once the articles are accepted by a journal, it takes time for coming online. Moreover, your question is unclear and lacks further details such as the following:

- Are you sure the journal is indexed by Scopus (have you verified by from Scopus site?)
- Whether the article has been published as "online-first"?
- Has it been indexed at the least by 'Google Scholar'? -- Usually, Google Scholar is fast in indexing as it directly captures the metadata from the journal site.

For the articles to appear in Scopus page, it will take some more time than Google Scholar takes. There are internal steps that are taken care before indexing the articles in Scopus. It usually takes 3 weeks to 2 months for an article to appear in Scopus (from my own experience), I can't provide data points. Also visit a similar question [here](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/63599/is-there-documentation-on-how-long-it-takes-before-publications-are-indexed-by-s).