# My article was not indexed by Web of Science (and possibly other paper databases) -- how to fix?

Tags: web-of-science

I recently published an article in a peer-reviewed journal. However, there was an issue with the assigned DOI at publication time which was not fixed until one month later (accessing the DOI led to '*Article Not Found*' errors).

Now, two months later (with the DOI now fixed), the article is still not indexed in major databases such as Web of Science. I believe this may be due to the incorrect DOI at the time of publication. I am worried that researchers may miss my article if it is not listed in Web of Science.

Is there a mechanism to fix such issues? I was not able to find any way to 'submit' entries to Web of Science -- it seems everything is automatically indexed.

Other relevant details:

- I am sure that the journal is indexed by Web of Science, and other articles published in the same issue of the journal can be found in a search
- I only know that it is missing in Web of Science, but there may be other databases from which it is missing. Is there a list of other major databases I should also check?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Did scopus choose not to add my paper (from an accepted journal) or did something go wrong?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/109055/did-scopus-choose-not-to-add-my-paper-from-an-accepted-journal-or-did-somethin)

Comment: @Anyon Thank you for the link, it looks like my article was indexed by Scopus but not WoS. I have sent a data change request for a missing article in WoS using [this web form](https://support.clarivate.com/ScientificandAcademicResearch/s/datachanges?language=en_US)

Comment: Do you find articles from the same issue of the journal you published in? Not sure how it is now, but WoS used to be notoriously slow with indexing new papers. You might just have to wait a little longer.

Comment: @Snijderfrey Yes, articles in the same issue (and even newer articles) are already indexed

Comment: I have faced a similar issue and have requested using form but I have not got any response in months.

Comment: @Hap  I have the same experience. My issue is still not fixed ~6 months after requesting a correction (I have not heard anything back)

Comment: UPDATE: after submitting [this web form](https://support.clarivate.com/ScientificandAcademicResearch/s/datachanges?language=en_US) almost 4 months ago, they have finally notified me that my article has been indexed. So it just takes a long time

Comment: @Superbee I also received the email today telling me that my article is indexed.

Answer (score 2):

In your situation, if it's bugging you out, request a [data change on Clarivate WoS](https://support.clarivate.com/ScientificandAcademicResearch/s/datachanges?language=en_US).

Personally though, I won't be too bothered as the DOI is now correct and indexed in Scopus.  Perhaps, check if it's Google Scholar '*indexed*'.

Comment: Yes, I have requested this many months ago to no response. And while my paper has been picked up by most other databases, I would prefer WoS so I can set up citation notifications as I do for my other papers.

Comment: UPDATE: They have finally indexed my article after ~4 months (after submitting the web form)