# Duration of article citations to appear in web of science

Tags: publications, citations, web-of-science

My articles were cited in a web of science (wos) journal. My citations appeared in google academic. But these citations still do not appear in wos.

Is there a certain period of time required for the citations of an article to appear in wos?

Comment: The [time lag until the citing papers are indexed](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/63599/17254) is presumably a lower bound, but I have no idea how tight of a bound it is.